# Exclusions in map in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary, filter

How do I create an exclusion for a array map in Ruby.
Here's what I want to achieve,

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
a.map.each do |x|
  b.map.each do |y|
    if !(x == 1 && y == 7)
      puts "#{x} and #{y}"
    elsif !(x == 4 && y == 8)
      puts "#{x} and #{y}"
    end
  end
end

1 and 5
1 and 6
1 and 7 # still here
1 and 8
2 and 5
2 and 6
2 and 7
2 and 8
3 and 5
3 and 6
3 and 7
3 and 8
4 and 5
4 and 6
4 and 7
4 and 8 # still here
```

However, it doesn't work, how do I add an exception to these values being processed by map? Also if it's possible to use inject/reject/filter function with the same goal.

Comment: You don't need those `map` calls BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain why 1 and 7 is still printing, step through the logic:

1. `if !(x == 1 && y == 7)`

   - `x == 1` is true and `y == 7` is true, therefore `!(true && true)` is false, this is skipped.
2. `elsif !(x == 4 && y == 8)`

   - the `if` was skipped, so the `elsif` is evaluated. `x == 4` is false (since x is still 1) and `y == 8` is false (since y is still 7). Therefore, `!(false && false)` is true, and the `puts` is reached.

Because `x` can never be both 1 and 4 at the same time and `y` can never be 7 and 8 at the same time, either your if statement or your elsif statement will always succeed, and since both branches print, the values will be always printed, no matter what x and y are.

As other answers said, you need to combine your clauses.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a problem of not understanding disjunctive semantics in an `if` statement.

If you want a value NOT to be printed at all, it must match ALL of the negative conditions. Since your predicate is the same (using `puts`), all you need to do is combine the `if` statements with an "and" keyword.

That is, something like:

```
if !(x == 1 && y == 7) and !(x == 4 && y == 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
a.map.each do |x|
  b.map.each do |y|
    if !(x == 1 && y == 7) && !(x == 4 && y == 8)
      puts "#{x} and #{y}"
    end
  end
end
```

(tested on [codepad](http://codepad.org/g6T0pGee))

Your old code only tested that `!(x == 1 && y == 7)` was true OR that `!(x == 4 && y == 8)`
was true - it did not test them both. So when x was 1 and y was 7, the first `puts` did not execute, but the second one did. Execute this code to trace it better:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
a.map.each do |x|
  b.map.each do |y|
    if !(x == 1 && y == 7)
      puts "First #{x} and #{y}"
    elsif !(x == 4 && y == 8)
      puts "SEcond #{x} and #{y}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this logic is also wrong.  it's the larger disjunction that is the issue, not the smaller

Comment: @James Baker: yeah, fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation using a patched Array class and the #reject method.

```
class Array
  def * arr
    outer = []
    self.each do |a|
      arr.each do |b|
        outer << [a,b]
      end
    end
    outer
  end
end


a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

c = (a * b).reject {|pair| pair == [1,7] || pair == [4,8]}

c.each {|pair| puts "#{pair[0]} and #{pair[1]}"}
```

Not sure about using the '*' operator, it would need a better implementation if you wanted to keep the ability to multiply arrays by a Fixnum, but i like the syntax for applying methods to a combination of the two arrays which is a fairly common requirement.

Comment: Err, what happened with `Array#zip`?

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović: This is the Cartesian Product, not `zip`. That's why `*` is kinda sorta appropriate, although the Cartesian Product is actually `×`. In particular, the Cartesian Product is *not* commutative, but you would normally expect `*` to be.

Comment: Ah, right, I apologize. BTW, there's `Array#product` in 1.9: http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000760

Comment: Thanks Mladen, 'product' is probably a better name. Array#product will come in handy when 1.9 becomes the standard ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea to seperate out the seperate steps:

1. compute the Cartesian Product of the two arrays: `a.product(b)`
2. filter out the unwanted pairs: `reject {|x, y| [[1, 7], [4, 8]].any? {|pair| [x, y] == pair }
   }`
3. convert to string: `map {|pair| pair.join(' and ') }`
4. print it: `puts`

That's what we end up with:

```
puts a.product(b).reject {|x, y|
  [[1, 7], [4, 8]].any? {|pair| [x, y] == pair }
}.map {|pair| pair.join(' and ') }
```